# Lotus notes enable api/data

Tags: rest, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am currently trying to develop an app for a company which uses a lotus notes 9.0.1 server. I am trying to work with their contractor who setup the server and I have no experience with lotus notes. I am going to use rest api to interact with the server but when I call GET on /api I see this the data is not enabled it seems to me that the Domino Data Service is not enabled for it can someone explain the steps to me for turning it on for the data view. So I can tell the contractor how.

Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADUX5.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using a search engine?

Each accessible database must be enabled to support the Domino® Data Service.
Tags: Enabling Domino Data Service on a database
To be able access a database with the Domino Data Service, each accessible database must be enabled to support the service.

Note: Remember to also make sure that the Data Service or any other service that you wish to access is first enabled on your server. The Core service is always enabled. Unlike the other services, the administrator does not have to intentionally enable the Core service. As long as the HTTP task is loaded, the Core service is available.
In Domino Designer or Notes®, do the following for each accessible database:
Open the database properties.
Click on the Advanced tab.
For Allow Domino Data Service, select either:
Views only to restrict access to views
Views and documents for full access

In Domino Designer, do the following for each accessible view:
Open the view properties.
Click on the Advanced tab.
Check Allow Domino Data Service operations.
Attempting to access a database that is not enabled typically returns error code 403 The Domino data service is not enabled for this database.

Attempting to access a view that is not enabled typically returns error code 403 The Domino data service is not enabled for this view.

https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Domino+Access+Services+9.0.1#action=openDocument&res_title=Enabling_Domino_Data_Service_on_a_database_das901&content=apicontent

Comment: Ya I have searched and that's what I concluded but I do not have access to change the database settings so I have to work through the contractor. They got it enabled for data, but now when I go into data it gives 
{
    "code":400,
    "text":"Bad Request",
    "message":"URI path must not include a database."
}

Comment: In that case, you should ask a new question about your new problem, and you should show your code and show the URL that you are sending with your GET request.